# CSS: text goes at left when float ends + nonbreakingline issue

Tags: css

I have a box where user activity will be inside.

Now I am having two issues.

The first one is that i have a float left element, and when this ends the text also goes at left. (issue1)

The second is that if you type in a non-breaking word/sentence, like eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee it wont break it and go under, but allows it going to the right, like it do not listen to the width specified.

Here is live of both issues:

http://jsfiddle.net/AB4Ls/5/

Help please, how can I solve this, and why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For first issue set element that contains text to be displayed as block and give it left-margin amount of floated element width.

```
display: block;
margin-left: 40px; /* adjust to your needs */
```

For second issue check this url: http://perishablepress.com/press/2010/06/01/wrapping-content/
Explanation is to long to repeat it here.

Comment: the second issue solution gave me another problem with my coding, please see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4480365/css-html-white-space-break-fix-and-now-cant-code-fine

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure it is possible you have such long words?
If true you can use css3 property [word-wrap](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-css3-text-20101005/#word-wrap0) or parse words with php before displaying it.

Comment: It's not that unreasonable - an html-encoded url would do it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're saying that you want the text in the issue 1 to NOT flow back under your image that you've floated to the left.

If so, just surround the text with a div tag and use `display: table-cell`.  This will put a "rigid border" if you will, around your text.

Comment: if the image isn't constant, you'll have to constantly adjust the margin-left of the image tag.  This way, it just works.  Always.

Comment: Actually I misunderstood your comment, @ivan - you are correct.  I should have said "set display:table-cell on the text container" (whatever that may be).